# Am I hearing the pitch accent of "家具売り場" correctly?

Tags: pitch-accent

I was watching the anime K-On and came across this sentence:

えっと家具売り場は…
https://instaud.io/_/2JFq.mp3

They were at a big store, wanted to buy a shelf and were looking for where they sell furniture.

Now my pitch accent dictionary says 売り場 is 平板:

うりば【LHH】

But I'm hearing this as:

かぐうりば 【HLHLL】

I would like to know if I'm hearing it correctly.

Comment: The thing is that compound words don't retain the original pitch contours of their constituent, but receive a single new pitch accent (after all compound words also count as single phonological words and hence can only possess a single pitch drop). In the case where the right component has at least three moras, compounds tend to retain the accent of the second word if that word is accented, or place it on the first mora of the second word (in the case of the second word being heiban), apparently a strategy helps speakers make out the boundary between the constituents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pronounced as かぐうりば{LHHLL}, which is one word with the third mora to be accented.

Comment: Pitch accent is hard, I can swear I hear かぐ as 頭高. Is this something specific for this expression かぐうりば? Or is there some predictable way in which this happens?

Comment: Sorry, but you heard it wrong.

Comment: A tone analizer says か:C#-D4, ぐ:G4, う:A4, り:G4, ば:C4, わ:A3-A#3-A3.